# Job Entrys Not Submitting to Database Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a forum where a user can enter in a job they are looking for which would be submitted to a database and then displayed on the following page. Only I can't get any of the data to upload, and I'm not sure why.

I'm also struggling with ways to error check. Any ideas?

```
// Check for job submission
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))

            //empty error array
            $error = array();

        // check for a things in the field

        if(empty($_POST['job']))
        {
            $error[] = 'Please fill in all required fields';

        }

        // iff there are no errors, insert the job listing into the database. 
        // otherwies, display error. 
        if(sizeof($error) == 0)
        {
            // insert job listing
            $query = "INSERT INTO job (
                                job_id, 
                                user_id, 
                                jobtitle,
                                company, 
                                location, 
                                summary,
                                responsibilities, 
                                skills
                                ) VALUES (
                                  null, 
                                  '{$_SESSION['user_id']}',
                                   '{$_POST['jobtitle']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['company']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['location']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['summary']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['responsibilities']}',
                                   '{$_POST['skills']}',
                                    NOW()
                                    )";

            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));

            // display a confirmation
            echo "<div class=\"alert alert success\">Your job listing has been added</div>";

        } else {

            // display error message
            foreach($error as $value)
            {
                echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\"{$value}</div>";
            }
        }

        ?>

        <!-- Job listing Form -->
        <form method="post" action="listings.php">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Job Title </label>
                <input name ="jobtitle" type="text" class="jobform"/>

                <label>Company/Organization</label>
                <input name="company" type="text" class="jobform"/>

                <label> Job Location </label>
                <input name ="location" type="text" class="jobform"/>

                <label> Job Responsibilities </label>
                <textarea name="summary" rows="8" cols="20" class="jobfourm"></textarea>

                <label> Job Responsibilities </label>
                <textarea name="responsibilities" rows="8" cols="20" class="jobfourm"></textarea>

                <label> Job Skills </label>
                <textarea name="skills" rows="8" cols="20" class="jobforum"></textarea>

            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" />
                </div>

        </form>

     </div>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Comment: @ Raptor I know, I'm kinda still learning about it, so for this practice sake I'm more trying to get down the basic working code before entering code to prevent injection

Comment: @ChristineAustin That's a sensible approach, but it's never too early for good security :)

Comment: This piece of code does not illustrate the problem enough. To debug, you can echo the `$query`, then you'll know which parameter is missing. My guess is that you didn't start the session. Also, first two lines have logic issues. What if `$_POST['submit']` is not set? the PHP codes below still execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bets are on your query:

```
 (
                                job_id, 
                                user_id, 
                                jobtitle,
                                company, 
                                location, 
                                summary,
                                responsibilities, 
                                skills
                                ) VALUES (
                                  null, 
                                  '{$_SESSION['user_id']}',
                                   '{$_POST['jobtitle']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['company']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['location']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['summary']}', 
                                   '{$_POST['responsibilities']}',
                                   '{$_POST['skills']}',
                                    NOW()
```

for what should be job_id, you're passing null. Now, I'm going to assume that all jobs must have a job ID, correct? You need to actually pass in a valid id, as I'm going to bet money (or rep) that that's a non nullable field in the table. Additionally, you've added a column in your values that you have not declared in your column name parameter.

Comment: You were right, I wasn't passing through the `jobdate` which corrilated to the `NOW()` and I guess that broke everything. Thank you so much! :]

Comment: Not a problem. It's always those tiny little things we miss ;)